# Is there any way to enable remote desktop with a password but not require typing one in when at the physical machine?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I'm running Windows 7 and would like to use remote desktop to connect to my home computer. As such i want to enable password security for remote desktop, but I do not want to have to enter a password to log into my computer if i'm physically at my computer. Is there any way to do this?

I am an administrator user and I want to have the same icons and configuration regardless of if i log in remotely or locally but i want only the remote connection to require a password. I read about being able to do something similar by adding another user account, but is there any way to do it so that the same icons and settings take affect regardless of how i log in?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate Question-Super user 161850

Answer (score 1):

Set up a LogMeIn free account and install the LogMeIn software on the computer. When accessing a passwordless computer, LogMeIn will require you to create and use a password for accessing the computer. This allows you to be "password free" when logging on locally, but requiring a password when logging on via LogMeIn, which should accomplish your objective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TweakUI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe) and set it to automatically logon with user credentials when you boot.  If you login through Remote Desktop it will lock the computer, but you can do as joeqwerty suggested and use logmein instead of remote desktop.  I think it has an option not to lock the pc when you log off.  I would suggest having a local password so that if somebody gets your logmein credentials they still can't login to your machine.